# Problem getting JSON contents with JSONValue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am using the objective-c json framework to parse some json from the lighthouse api - http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

I've used the framework before with other apis with no issues although i seem to have come to a dead end when trying to grab the results from the lighthouse api using JSONValue.

It appears the value is being returned incorrectly:

```
NSArray *results = [json_string JSONValue];

for (NSDictionary *project in results){
    NSLog(@"project found");
}
```

This loop only runs once although i know there are atleast 7 objects for it to itterate through in the JSON string. project is also being set as a string and not a NSDictionary, i know this as calling objectForKey on project causes an error.

```
[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm pretty stumped here and hope this isn't an issue with the string being returned from the Lighthouse api and i am just trying to get the contents incorrectly, my json string is here: http://pastie.org/1390233

Comment: Is that the parsed JSON (e.g., a JavaScript object) or unparsed (a string)? It _looks_ parsed to me - what does the JSON framework expect to receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser's behavior is correct. The dictionary `results` contains only 1 key with the name `projects` which is an array. To loop through each individual project, you need to enumerate this `projects` property.

```
NSArray *projects = [results objectForKey:@"projects"];

for(NSDictionary *item in projects) {
    NSDictionary *project = [item objectForKey:@"project"];
    // now project should have the desired keys
}
```

Comment: Exactly right. It took me a bit when I first started parsing JSON to recognize that things can be nested quite deeply, e.g. Projects->Project->Results->Result. Nested enumerators, as @Anurag demonstrates, are a great way to tackle them.