# I use JSON but there is exception [NSString objectForKey:]

Tags: json, nsstring, nsdictionary

i read information in my database i use JSON but there is exception

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x603dfb0'

I think this part :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSArray *array = [str JSONValue];
    if (!array)
         return;

    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {

         NSDate *d = [fmt dateFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]];
         NSLog(@"%@",d);
         [eventPHP addObject:[Events eventsNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"title_event"]  description:[dict objectForKey:@"description"] date:d]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Will probably need to see the json string (or a close example) to see what it looks like. Plus try valueForKey instead of objectForKey as a test (I think they behave differently, but want to see).

Comment: Added a line from another post that looked similar in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: The error message says that you are sending `objectForKey` which is a method on NSDictionary to a NSString. It looks like your types are not what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

"pass the linker a special flag, ‘-ObjC’. Adjusting the build settings of my project to include this flag in the ‘Other linker flags’"

according to:

http://beatworm.co.uk/blog/computers/using-categories-on-objective-c-classes-in-a-static-library/

EDIT:
[Why it is terminating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206163/why-it-is-terminating)

EDIT2:
OK, not exactly sure (as I've never done this type of coding), but given the json data:

```
{"event":[
  {"eve_date":"2011-12-18","eve_time":"00:00:06","title_event":"Google event","description":"Google event for IT student"},
  {"eve_date":"2011-12-29","eve_time":"00:00:08","title_event":"microsoft event","description":"microsoft event for IT student"}
]}
```

The first object is an array labeled "event" which might be throwing you off.

So, try replacing this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {

     NSDate *d = [fmt dateFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]];
     NSLog(@"%@",d);
     [eventPHP addObject:[Events eventsNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"title_event"]  description:[dict objectForKey:@"description"] date:d]];
}
```

with:

```
NSArray *array2 = [array objectForKey:@"event"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array2) {

     NSDate *d = [fmt dateFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]];
     NSLog(@"%@",d);
     [eventPHP addObject:[Events eventsNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"title_event"]  description:[dict objectForKey:@"description"] date:d]];
}
```

using: [Problem getting JSON contents with JSONValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485061/problem-getting-json-contents-with-jsonvalue)

Not sure if that will work, but if it does, it will make more sense to me.

Comment: i add it but still the exception exist

Comment: @TahanieALsanie yes, after looking around it seems the problem is probably something else... I'll put a link in the answer.

Comment: I tray change my code but this happen :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6415800'

Comment: I use kal source to represent event and read events from database server


> {"event":[{"eve_date":"2011-12-18","eve_time":"00:00:06","title_event":"Google event","description":"Google event for IT student"},{"eve_date":"2011-12-29","eve_time":"00:00:08","title_event":"microsoft event","description":"microsoft event for IT student"}]}


and use JSON with kal source for calendar

Answer (score 0):

I solve exception by change location files class of JSON but the event doesn't

display in calendar .

the calendr is display but didn't contain any event

hint: when i put url in browser the content of database display